# What are the best astronomy blogs and podcasts?

Tags: soft-question, astronomy, big-list

For someone who likes learning about astronomy what are the blogs and/or podcasts that I should be following?

Comment: Community wiki?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3432/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16626/2451

Comment: I enjoy Neil degrasse Tyson's Star Talk Radio, but it's more for entertainment value than educational content. Thought I'd mention it just the same.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some of the ones I enjoy

- [Universe Today](http://www.universetoday.com/) - Also has weekly Hangouts on G+
- [Bad Astronomy](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/) - His book is great too!!!
- [Tom's Astronomy](http://tomsastroblog.com/)
- [NASA Watch](http://nasawatch.com/)
- [Astronomy Magazine](http://www.astronomy.com/) - Site has good content, and I love the magazine
- [Hobby Space](http://hobbyspace.com/nucleus/HSblog.php)
- [NASA](http://blogs.nasa.gov/cm/newui/blog/blogs.jsp)

Answer (score 5):

there are three web pages that I think are very good websites in terms of astronomy:

- [Tom's astronomy blog](http://tomsastroblog.com/)
- [Aanda](http://www.aanda.org/)
- [Zidbits](http://zidbits.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You might also like to check out

- http://www.jodcast.net/
- http://www.slackerastronomy.org/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the UK there is a list on the Astronomy Clubs website:

[Astronomy Podcasts](http://www.astronomyclubs.co.uk/astronomy-podcasts)